# Fuel httpGet() responseString, Failure: com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.BubbleFuelError: null

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-fuel

### Problem

I want to get the result of a get request by doing a synchronous call to an API by using Fuel as Httpclient.
I'm using Fuel in an Android (Anko) project.
The call is just a simple get request which always fails with this error:

> Failure: com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.BubbleFuelError: null
>
> Caused by: com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.BubbleFuelError: null

### Background

I want to make a function for returning a result of a simple get request using Fuel. But I'm not able to retrieve the the result synchronous.

I cannot find any useful information about this subject on the internet.

I tried to await the result by using coroutines and use the awaitStringResponse function.  -->  Did not worked as expected.

Just responded to a Github issue covering this topic (marked as bug).
https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel/issues/606

Is there some workaround?

### Code example

*This code is working:*

```
requestUrl.httpGet().responseString { _, _, result ->
     when (result) {
          is Result.Success -> {
             // do something on success
          }
          is Result.Failure -> {
             // do something on fail
          }
     }
}
```

But using this function, I am not able to return the result.

*This code is NOT working*

```
val (_,_,result)= Fuel.get(requestUrl).responseString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this with kotlin coroutines.

```
fun doRequest() = runBlocking {
    val (_, _, result) = Fuel.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1").awaitStringResponse()
    result
}
```

Using runBlocking will block the current thread until it's completed.

*Source: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html*

When you don't want to block the current thread you can start this function in a new thread like this:

```
Thread(
    Runnable {
      val result = doRequest()
      Log.e("Result", result)
    }
).start()
```

If someone knows a better way to handle this, please show your solution.